# Controlling for seasonality in marketing mix modeling

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, seasonality, marketing

I am estimating a marketing mix model on sales using linear regression. My goal is to estimate the effect of marketing and branding on sales (not forecast the future). I have 4 years worth of monthly sales and media data and I want to use seasonality as a covariate in my analyses because there is a clear seasonal sales pattern in my data.

My question is:

- I used seasonal decomposition on my sales data (in SPSS > Forecasting > Seasonal Decomposition) and have:
  a) A seasonal effect - i.e., a continuous variable that shows the cyclical pattern of sales by month (which does not change year over year)
  b) A deseasoned trend - i.e., the overall growth in sales over time without the seasonal effects (showing growth year over year)
  c) Residuals

What I don't understand is which of these variables to use as covariates in my regression: Do I want the seasonal effect, the deseasoned trend, or both? My goal is to understand the effect of marketing on sales over the past years.